# Execute command on files found in terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to concatenate linux commands - so I want to lint files using the lint command. But I only want to lint files with the .js extension. I can find all these files by running this in the terminal:

`find ./my-folder -name "*.js"`

But how can I run the lint command on just these files in the terminal?

Comment: [Understanding the `-exec` option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/108618).

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution, using just `find` with `-exec` to run the command:

`find ./my-folder -name "*.js" -exec lint_command {} +`

`+` is used instead of `\;` to have `find` substitute multiple filenames instead of only one, similar to `xargs`.

Comment: N.B. don't use this command as written, because rm will permanently *remove* the js files.

Comment: @stib Oops, fixed

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `xargs` commnd. :)  I am a "windows lover".. but as far as I can tell.. windows sure doesn't have anything as cool as this with cmd.exe.

Try something like this:

`find ./my-folder -name "*.js" | xargs rm`

In this example, each instance gathered by `find` will get passed to the `rm` command.

Comment: N.B. don't use this command as written, because rm will permanently remove the js files.

Comment: btw, cmd.exe is from the age when dinosaurs ruled the earth. Just use powershell, which is an object oriented shell: `ls ./my-folder *.js |%{ lint $_.fullname }`

Comment: @stib .. this is irrelevant.  He is asking for help with the linux command line.  Why are you posting powershell code?  I was just pointing out that cmd.exe couldn't do this.. and I COME from the age when dinosaurs ruled the earth. ;)  I answered his question which was "how do I do this in linux?" I also prefer SuperStormer answer to my own.

Comment: Ah, you were the one who brought up cmd.exe in an answer to a Linux question, but rock on.